# Relative Path for Sqlite database via DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlite?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core 2.2 project where the back-end needs to open a DbContext to a Sqlite database.

I need something like:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Data\Database.db");
```

However the database is in `\Data\` which is relative to the root of the project.

Should this not work or do I have to add additional code to determine a relative path here?

Comment: It should work. If it doesn't, did you forget to add a `<ItemGroup><None Update="Data\Database.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"  /></ItemGroup>` in your `*.csproj`?

Comment: are you facing an error while migrating or you didn't try it?

Comment: @alim91 I tried it, of course :)  I will update the question with the specific error relating to not finding the file

Comment: ok, it will better, but did you create "Data" folder first?

Answer (score 0):

instead of a backward slash "\" use a forward slash "/"

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Data/Database.db");
}
```